# How's the etymology 'exert' "probably due to antithesis with inserĕre"?

Tags: etymology, english

["exert, v."](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/66113) *OED Online*. Accessed 26 June 2019.

> [image]

Can someone please expound the sentence underlined in green?

Answer (score 1):

Attaching *ex* "out" to *serere* "to bind" isn't really an obvious formation: what does it mean to "bind something out"?

So more likely, what happened is: *in-serere* "to bind in" became common, becoming the ancestor of modern English "insert" and taking on that meaning. And then when people needed an opposite for "insert", replacing *in-* with *ex-* was an obvious choice.

So *ex-serere* arose, meaning "to bring out", as in the opposite of "insert". Over time this evolved into the modern meaning of "exert".